# Can I not setup multiple redirects using apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have single web application on the server with multiple domain names (pittsburgh-app.com, philadelphia-app.com, etc).

Now the domain names are changing to (new-pittsburgh-app.com, new-philly-app.com, and so on).

So when I setup the following redirection in a new conf file it works:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>   ServerName pittsburgh-app.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://new-pittsburgh-app.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

But the second redirection does not:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>   ServerName philadelphia-app.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://new-philly-app.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I not setup multiple redirections this way?

NB: I setup the second redirection in a separate conf file as well.  Port 8080 necessary because that's what the load balancer uses.

Comment: Try use `%{SERVER_NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the virtual host directives need to be unique, the two you have listed seem to be the same:

old: `<VirtualHost *:8080>`

new:
    `<VirtualHost www.pittsburgh-app.com:8080>`

etc.

Comment: Then I get the following error: [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name pittsburgh-app.com -- ignoring! Note that I am doing this on a test server and my laptop's hosts file is pointing to the test server's ip but urls are not setup on a public dns

Comment: have you tried with without the www?